# Why 'ApplicationRecord.descendants.count' return only 1 but In my rails Application there are many inheriting models of ApplicationRecord?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I ran following code in rails console:

```
ApplicationRecord.descendants.count # It returns only 1
```

Even there are many inheriting classes from the "ApplicationRecord" are available inside project_root/app/models/ in rails 5.2.4.

Answer (score 2):

The models won't be loaded when you open the console, you can use [`#eager_load!`](https://apidock.com/rails/Rails/Application/eager_load!) after opening the rails console to change that:

```
Rails.application.eager_load!
```